# Tableau_ How to I attach raw data source while schedule report

Tags: tableau-api

My question is as same as I mentioned on title. Mostly, my report doesn't need to provide raw data. However, financial dept would not only need the final report but raw data. I have a schedule to send report to them with dashboard but they would also need the raw data for double checking. Is anyone know how to attach raw data while schedule report? The raw data would be the data source as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could build something like this in your dashboard. http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info and sorry for late reply. I know this way would work, but there's no control of the output of csv. The columns of output will be sorted by alphabet. Anyway, thank you!!!